# What takes up so much space in the newer (Vista, 7, 8, 10) Windows installations?

Tags: windows, disk-space

Without the obvious hogs like hybernation and paging files, shadow copy, saved update and installation files, what takes up so much space that it needs ~7-10 gigabytes for a fresh installation? [Wikipedia lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT#Hardware_requirements) that older versions of Windows NT required ~1.5-2GB (Windows XP and Server 2003), and then from Vista onwards it blows up to 15GB. What's in those extra 13 gigabytes?

I suppose there have to be new built-in apps that didn't come with XP and the new Aero Glass and theming textures, but it can't possibly take up all that much. What else does it contain? And how did XP and older Windows editions could work just fine requiring much less installation space?

Comment: I consider this as an extraordinarily interesting question.

Comment: See [Disk Space](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/e7/2008/11/19/disk-space/) for a complete explanation.

Comment: WinSxS and the new CBS based setup: http://superuser.com/a/1098724/174557 . If you tried to change installed features in xp, you needed to insert the XP DVD. having the files already on disk in winsxs removes the steps to insert a dvd, but it uses more space